# Visual Studio 2017 editor simplify null reference check suggestion not working with generic parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editor

I've just noticed, that the editor suggests that I can simplify my expression of assigning a field in a constructor with a null reference check. However when doing this with a generic type, this doesn't really work.

For example in a class like

```
public class Generic<T>
{
    private readonly T _field;

    public Generic(T value)
    {
         if(value == null)
             throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

         _field = value;
    }
}
```

the editor suggests to simplify the syntax in the constructor to

```
public Generic(T value)
{
     _field = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
}
```

Now this obviously doesn't work because of the generic parameter which can't be evaluated for null with the null coalescing operator `??`, however the editor still suggests it.

I was wondering now if there might be a way to use that shorthand notation with a generic parameter? And if not, if it should be considered a bug within the editor for not checking the type of the parameter when suggesting such a change.

Also would it change if there is a restriction of the generic type to an interface like the following?

```
public class Generic<T> where T : IInterface
```

Comment: Is T always going to be a reference type?

Comment: In this special case, yes. But i was thinking more of a general answer.

Comment: Oh, well in this example you can tell it that T is a reference type `public class Generic<T> where T : class`. I don't know the answer to the general case.